# ls /dev/sd cannot access: No such file or directory Error

Tags: linux, ls

How this error should be resolved?

```
[root@ljl ~]# ls /dev/sd ls: cannot access /dev/sd: No such file or directory
```

Comment: [root@ljl ~]# ls /dev/sd
ls: cannot access /dev/sd: No such file or directory

Comment: What is the question, exactly?

Comment: Please, post text as text, not as pictures as text. We don't want to critique your use of color of perspective, we want to copy&paste your text into Google, for example. Also, it makes your question impossible to answer for visually impaired users, as well as users relying on text-to-speech readers for other reasons. It also makes it impossible to index and search the question both by Stack Exchange's own search engine as well as Google, Bing, etc.

Comment: The error occurs because there is no device file or directory named `/dev/sd`. I see two possible resolutions: Either don't execute the command (I am serious - why do you need to run this command?), or create a device file or directory named `/dev/sd` then try again. In case you are doing this on Linux, SCSI disks are normally named `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sdb` etc., and I have never heard of `/dev/sd`. However, you may run this command on a different operating system. Therefore, provide more information: What do you want to achieve, and what is your operating system?

Comment: i want to check the subfiles under /dev/sd  and  this question had been solved..thanks @muru

Comment: This is a great advice which can teach me to have a logical thinking，thanks！@berndbausch

Comment: this will be a good suggestion， thanks！@Jörg W Mittag

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is normal `/dev/sd` simply doesn't exist, if you are trying to list all (SATA) drives on your system you need to use `ls /dev/sd*` (`*` is used to match anything so it will list `/dev/sda`, `/dev/sda1`, `/dev/sdb` etc.). Or if you are looking for information about block devices on your system, I recommend using `lsblk` which way better than listing content of `/dev`.

Comment: dear Sir 
thanks for your help!
BR